# Export of means in a dataframe generated by describe()

Tags: r, export, mean

I am trying to compute the means of many variables based on a factor variable and then export those means in a data frame.

```
library(psych)
DATA = data.frame(labels=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),data=matrix(1:36,nrow=6))
DATA
descriptivesD <- by(cbind(DATA$data.1, DATA$data.2, DATA$data.3), DATA$label, describe)
descriptivesD

str(descriptivesD)
all.means <- descriptivesD$mean
all.means
```

I am pretty sure that the assignment of `descriptivesD$mean` is wrong since each level of the categorical variable is a data.frame that contains the means, but I have no idea how to export them in a data frame.

My first problem is that when I use the function mean instead of describe in the by() I get error. So I continue with describe and try to export the only the mean-elements.

Ideally, I would like to save the means in a dataframe where the first column would be the level of the factor variable that they were computed from, and then each column would be the mean of each variable

```
label data.1 data.2 data.3
a     5      6      1
b     2      5      2
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is a `list`, so a pretty direct way to get the information is to use `lapply` or `sapply`:

```
> lapply(descriptivesD, `[`, "mean")
$a
   mean
V1    2
V2    8
V3   14

$b
   mean
V1    5
V2   11
V3   17

> sapply(descriptivesD, `[`, "mean")
$a.mean
[1]  2  8 14

$b.mean
[1]  5 11 17
```

---

If you want it as a `data.frame` or a `matrix`, here are a few options which differ really mostly in presentation.

```
> do.call(rbind, sapply(descriptivesD, `[`, "mean"))
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
a.mean    2    8   14
b.mean    5   11   17

> data.frame(sapply(descriptivesD, `[`, "mean"))
  a.mean b.mean
1      2      5
2      8     11
3     14     17

> do.call(cbind, lapply(descriptivesD, `[`, "mean"))
   mean mean
V1    2    5
V2    8   11
V3   14   17
```

---

***However***, you can also achieve this pretty directly in base R using `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(cbind(data.1, data.2, data.3) ~ labels, DATA, mean)
  labels data.1 data.2 data.3
1      a      2      8     14
2      b      5     11     17
```

Comment: +1 for aggregate! I was about to answer with `ddply` but `aggregate` fulfills the need of getting rid of the non-user-friendly `by` output!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(DATA)

dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = labels]
#   labels data.1 data.2 data.3 data.4 data.5 data.6
#1:      a      2      8     14     20     26     32
#2:      b      5     11     17     23     29     35
```